# Why does Visual Studio show older version next to project name despite an upgrade?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I opened a Visual Studio 2013 solution in VS2017. I was prompted to convert my solution and projects, which I did. If I right-click on a project and select Retarget, I can choose to use Windows SDK 10.0.17134.0 and Platform Toolset v141, I've done this manually as well. I can build my projects and run them (this is a makefile-based project by the way). Yet Visual Studio still shows "(Visual Studio 2013)" next to the projects' names. Why and how do I get it to go away?

[image]

Comment: It only converts the projects in the solution that *have* to be converted.  Apparently that Core project did not.

Comment: @HansPassant is there a way to force it to convert? I thought that was what Retargeting was supposed to do... Core.vcxproj contains tools version 15.0: <Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17134.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can force the upgrade by right clicking on the project in the Solution Explorer and selecting "Upgrade VC++ Compiler and Libraries".  It will then pop up the normal Project Upgrade dialog.  Click OK to upgrade the project.